# not getting the re directed url in python

Tags: python, url, redirect

On clicking on each link in this http://india.gov.in/topics/health-family-welfare/health ,each of them are redirected to another domain ,when i have fetched all the links and tried to get the redirected url,then the below error was getting ,so i took one url and put it on browser ,it it is not redirected ,how can i get that redirected web urls .When i have tried to print the status code of the url using the just below code it was returing 404 stsua but the contents were printing ,does that mean i will not be able to fetch  thoose redirected url

```
try:
    print urllib2.urlopen(link).read()
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print e.code
    print e.msg
    print e.headers
    print e.fp.read()
```

I have tried this code to get the redirected url ,but i am getting an error instead

```
import urllib2, httplib

httplib.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
request = urllib2.Request("http://www.india.gov.in/redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fmohfw.nic.in&nid=MjU3NTBuZXducGk=")
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
f = opener.open(request)
print f.url
```

prints:

```
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Comment: I can reporoduce your problem. It seems, like the redirecting server, handling the first request, is requiring some wider context like cookies, some headers or so. I will check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page redirect seems to require referer being set to the page, you start from.

Your call is not setting up Referer, so it fails.

Note, that if you take the url into clipboard and try to open it in browser, you end up on page with title ""requested page not found"

Using my favourite `requests`, I can reproduce the problem and also show, that with header "Referer" it works

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = "http://www.india.gov.in/redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fmohfw.nic.in&nid=MjU3NTBuZXducGk="
>>> req = requests.get(url)
>>> req
<Response [404]>
>>> req.reason
'Not Found'
```

Now try the same with "Referer" header set to the page of origin

```
>>> headers = {"Referer": "http://india.gov.in/topics/health-family-welfare/health"}
>>> req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
>>> req
<Response [200]>
```

You shall get the same result with whatever http library (or switch to `requests` to have your live easier).

Comment: I am getting the status code as 200 ,But i am not getting the redirected url when i have tried to print it like
 print req.url ,

Comment: @FazeelaAbuZohra I have even bigger problem today, when I repeat my steps, which were working yesterday, I get today status 404. Next thing to try would be cookies, but this I cannot do today.

Comment: Thank you for helping,when you get time please make it up to my problem.Thank you once more